# tictactoe program keeps looping until draw even if it's won

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite

It keeps asking for input even though it's already won until you fill all the empty spaces and at that moment it says you drew.

```js
function getboardstring(gameBoard) {
  let string = ``;
  for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
    i % 3 === 0 ? string += `\n` : ``;
    gameBoard[i] === null ? string += i : string += gameBoard[i];
  }
  return string;
}

function getUserInput(nextPlayerSymbol, gameBoard) {
  return +prompt(`${getboardstring(gameBoard)}\n dove vuoi posizionare la ${nextPlayerSymbol}?`);
}

function isMoveValid(move, gameBoard) {
  if (gameBoard[move] === null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function makeAMove(gameBoard, nextPlayerSymbol) {
  // clone the game board before placing moves in it
  let newGameBoard = [...gameBoard];
  let move = 0;
  do {
    move = getUserInput(nextPlayerSymbol, gameBoard);
  } while (!isMoveValid(move, gameBoard));
  newGameBoard[move] = nextPlayerSymbol;
  return newGameBoard;
}

function hasLastMoverWon(currentPlayerSymbol, gameBoard) {
  let winnerCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let [i1, i2, i3] of winnerCombos) {
    if (gameBoard[i1] === currentPlayerSymbol &&
      gameBoard[i2] === gameBoard[i1] &&
      gameBoard[i3] === gameBoard[i1]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function isGameOver(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol) {
  // 1. check if there is a winner 
  if (hasLastMoverWon(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol) === true) {
    alert(`${currentPlayerSymbol} has won the game!`);
    return true;
  }
  // 2. check if the board is full
  else if (gameBoard.includes(null) === false) {
    alert(`game ended in a draw`);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function ticTacToe() {
  let gameBoard = new Array(9).fill(null)
  let currentPlayerSymbol = null;
  do {
    currentPlayerSymbol = currentPlayerSymbol === `X` ? `O` : `X`;
    gameBoard = makeAMove(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol);
  } while (!isGameOver(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol));
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML here; use the snippet edit link -->
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question about your _code_, not your game. Please update the snippet demo above with some HTML so we can see the problem.

Comment: Protip: The innards of `isMoveValid()` can just be `return gameBoard[move] === null`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter order of `function hasLastMoverWon` was wrong. It works when corrected:

```js
function getboardstring(gameBoard) {
let string = ``;
for(let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
    i % 3 === 0 ? string += `\n`: ``;
    gameBoard[i] === null ? string += i : string += gameBoard[i];
}
return string;
}
function getUserInput(nextPlayerSymbol, gameBoard) {
return prompt(`${getboardstring(gameBoard)}\n dove vuoi posizionare la ${nextPlayerSymbol}?`);
}

function isMoveValid(move, gameBoard) {
if (gameBoard[move] === null) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function makeAMove(gameBoard, nextPlayerSymbol) {
// clone the game board before placing moves in it
let newGameBoard = [...gameBoard];
let move = 0;
do {
    move = getUserInput(nextPlayerSymbol, gameBoard);
    if (move == null) throw move
} while (!isMoveValid(move, gameBoard));
newGameBoard[move] = nextPlayerSymbol;
return newGameBoard;
}

function hasLastMoverWon(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol) {
let winnerCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2], 
    [3, 4, 5], 
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7], 
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8], 
    [2, 4, 6]
];
for (let [i1, i2, i3] of winnerCombos) {
    if (gameBoard[i1] === currentPlayerSymbol &&
        gameBoard[i2] === gameBoard[i1] &&
        gameBoard[i3] === gameBoard[i1]) {
        return true;
    }       
}
return false;
}

function isGameOver(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol) {
// 1. check if there is a winner 
if (hasLastMoverWon(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol) === true) {
    alert(`${currentPlayerSymbol} has won the game!`);
    return true;
}
// 2. check if the board is full
else if (gameBoard.includes(null) === false) {
    alert(`game ended in a draw`);
    return true;
}
return false;
}

function ticTacToe() {
let gameBoard = new Array(9).fill(null)
let currentPlayerSymbol = null;
do {
    currentPlayerSymbol = currentPlayerSymbol === `X` ? `O` : `X`;
    gameBoard = makeAMove(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol);
} while (!isGameOver(gameBoard, currentPlayerSymbol));
}

try { ticTacToe() } catch (e) { if (e) throw e }
```